# Moving items within a listbox that is filled from list of KeyValuePair. Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listbox

[image]

I fill a listbox from a list with this code:

```
     uList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Id, item.Name));
     listBoxHome.DataSource = uList;
     listBoxHome.DisplayMember = "Value";
     listBoxHome.ValueMember = "Key";
```

then i copy all the items in a new dialog form(Subtitiution) and I fill a checkedListBox1

```
     private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxHome.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            sub.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(listBoxHome.Items[i].ToString());
        }                        
        this.Opacity = 0.7;     
        sub.ShowDialog();
    }
```

[image]
Then I get the selected indexes of the selected items into a list.
I want to choose 5 items and then place them in the first 5 places of the listbox.Game is the first form.I try the following code but it gives me error. Any idea?

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        foreach (int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
        {
            indexes.Add(indexChecked);
        }
        Game game = new Game();
        foreach (int PlayingInd in indexes) // Loop through List with foreach
        {
            game.listBoxHome.Items.Insert(0, game.listBoxHome.Items[PlayingInd]);
            game.listBoxHome.Items.RemoveAt(PlayingInd);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you move the item up or down?  Not with a dictionary as your source, no.  Change the source to a List<Players> instead.

Comment: I use dictionary because I want to get also the ids with the text.I want to be able the change the first 5 places(now playing players).

Comment: ..and I suggested you don't.  You can't re-order a dictionary.  Make a class that has your player id and names.  You could then have "everything" you need in that class: bench player, etc.  If you are dead set on this, then try changing the dictionary to a List of KeyValuePairs.

Comment: Now that I have list of KeyValuePairs how can move items?